# pip install from one virtualenv into another from scipt?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-venv

I'm writing a script to automate the setup of new python projects. I created a new virtualenv like this:

```
class PyAutoProject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.venv_dir = 'venv'

    def create_venv(self):
        envbuilder = venv.EnvBuilder(with_pip=True)
        envbuilder.create(self.venv_dir)
```

I want to install packages into that venv from the script, while it runs from it's own virtualenv. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer 5 years later...

```
import venv
import subprocess
from os.path import abspath

venv_dir = "venv"
venv.create(venv_dir, with_pip=True)

# assuming requirements.txt in same dir as this script
run(["bin/pip", "install", "-r", abspath("requirements.txt")], cwd=venv_dir)
```